# Does S3Object.getObjectMetadata() trigger a download of the object?

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

If I have a S3Object called `s3Object` and I want to get its metadata like so:

```
ObjectMetadata objectMetadata = s3Object.getObjectMetadata();
```

does the call to this function trigger a download of the object from S3?  Or is only the metadata downloaded?  I'm trying to estimate how much data consumption over WiFi or 3G will result from this function call (I'm guessing its on the order of a few bytes if it's only getting the metadata, but obviously much more if it has to download the object).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Calling `.getObjectMetadata` makes a HEAD call](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectHEAD.html). It isn't a full GET- in other words, it doesn't get the object itself.

Comment: Does it make a HEAD call for every call on the same object?

Answer (score 1):

I just wondered this myself, and confirmed with tcpdump that only about 1-2 KB is downloaded for a call to this method.